# Update variable used by Grunt Template

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using Grunt Templates, but wondering how I can update the variable which is used. Please check out the example below.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    module.exports = function(grunt) {

        grunt.initConfig({

            directory: 'deploy', // I want to be able to update this

            concat: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';\n\n',
                    banner: '/*! Last edited: <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY */\n\n'
                },
                js_site: {
                    src: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/src/*.js',
                    dest: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/site.js',
                },
                js_vendor: {
                    src: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/vendor/*.js',
                    dest: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/vendor.js',
                }
            },

        });


        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

        grunt.registerTask('watch', function() {

            var args    = process.argv;
            var dir     = args[args.indexOf('--dir') + 1];

            // Now update the directory variable above

        });
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    module.exports = function(grunt) {

        grunt.initConfig({

            directory: 'deploy', // I want to be able to update this

            concat: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';\n\n',
                    banner: '/*! Last edited: <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY */\n\n'
                },
                js_site: {
                    src: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/src/*.js',
                    dest: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/site.js',
                },
                js_vendor: {
                    src: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/vendor/*.js',
                    dest: '<%= directory %>/assets/js/vendor.js',
                }
            },

        });


        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

        grunt.registerTask('watch', function() {

            var args    = process.argv;
            var dir     = args[args.indexOf('--dir') + 1];

            // Now update the directory variable above
            grunt.config.set('directory', dir);
        });
    };

})();
```

Comment: When I run 'grunt watch --dir phase1', it just says 'Running "watch" task Done, without errors.' and exits the command prompt instead of actually doing watch. Know what's up?